# Make 2 panels and load 2 website in one page html, and zoom in zoom out without effect to other panel

Tags: html, css, zooming, panel

```css
html,body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
     <iframe src="link_v1" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"                           
                                    style="height: 100%; 
                                                width: 49%; float: left; " height="100%" width="49%"
                                   align="left">
                                  </iframe>  

     <iframe src="link_v2" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"  
                                        style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%;

                                        width: 49%; " height="100%" width="49%"                                 
                                         align="right">
                                        </iframe>
```

I want to make 2 panels in one page. and for example when I zoom in on one of the panels, the other panel will not zoom in

[this the picture what i want, i figure it out but i cannt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQnuA.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i used iframe, look my latest snippet, what i want is if i zoom one of panels, it will only zoom  inside the panel or iframe not full of webpage